Скрыть колонки в dash_table.DataTable()
У меня 2 колонки.
В первой значение, во второй класс значения.

Я через
style_data_conditional = [{'if': {'filter_query': f'{{Class}} = 0',
'column_id': 'column1'},'color': 'green'}, {'if': {'filter_query': f'{{Class}} = 3',
'column_id': column1},'color': 'red'}]

в @callback создаю условие для подсветки. Далее мне нужно удалить колонки со значением класса, из выходной таблицы, просто их drop'нуть нельзя, стили не применяются. Я попробовал
{'if': {'column_id':'Class'},'maxWidth': '0px',}

прописать далее в стиле, сужение ширины колонки до 0 не применяется, хотя изменение цвета применяется. Вопрос: Как удалить ненужные колонки из таблицы если они учавствуют в стиле для других колонок
